# git ls-remote --heads to ignore specific branches

Tags: github

> git ls-remote --heads
> Displays references available in a remote branches along with the associated commit IDs.

git ls-remote --heads https://github.com/companyname/gitreponame release/branchname-*.*

Its give me the list of all the remote branch like below

- release/branchname-1.0
- release/branchname-2.0
- release/branchname-3.0-TP
- release/branchname-3.0
- release/branchname-4.0-TP
- release/branchname-4.0

IS there  a way I can ignore these **-TP** bnranches from my list

Answer (score 0):

`git ls-remote` doesn't offer a built-in way to do this, but you can easily do it with `grep`:

```
$ git ls-remote --heads origin | grep -ve '-TP$'
```